# Yandex api SuggestView get city

Tags: javascript, yandex, yandex-api

I have a city field, and I need to autofill ONLY CITIES when I start typing.

```
function onLoad (ymaps) {
    var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('city');      
}
```

My function enters not only the city, but also the full address, but I only need the city. And you only need to use Yandex Api